# Does GetComponent<>() impact performance

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

Just as title say does GetComponent() does impact a lot on performance.

I am asking this because I do not like doing it like this:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerStats playerStats = this.GetComponent<PlayerStats>();

    void Update()
    {
        var something = playerStats.Asd;
    }
}
```

Instead of that i like using it like this:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        var something = this.GetComponent<PlayerStats>().Asd;
    }
}
```

Reason for that is because i like breaking code in lot of scripts (it is easier for me to later change something if needed and also use one script for multiple objects) and so if i have a lot of scripts i need to see if i have already defined `PlayerStats playerStats....` but not only this one but about a lot of them.

So is using second approach going to slow down my game a lot?

Comment: You may want to read https://answers.unity.com/questions/185164/what-more-should-i-be-caching-within-my-scripts.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main appeal of using the first approach is that you can set those variables to be public, and in turn access them directly from the Unity Editor, allowing you to drag and drop components as you feel like it.

The second instance of your `GetComponent` function call means that you aren't caching your variables, slowing down your code with potentially unnecessary checks. So my advice would be to stick with the first instance in which your variable is defined in memory and then altered, rather than being allocated memory each time and then altered.

And a side note. You do not need to call `this.GetComponent` if the script is attached to an object since the script derives from a `MonoBehaviour`; you can just call `GetComponent<type>()` and go about your merry day. :)

Comment: Well thank you for explanation. I know about `this` but i like to point it like that because it looks organized for me and easier to understand :D

Answer (score 9):

It's worth noting that your first script is invalid and won't compile. The correct way to do that is to make it a global variable but cache or initialize  the script in the `Start` or `Awake` function. These functions run once and are used for initialization.

Something like this:

```
PlayerStats playerStats;

void Start()
{
    playerStats  = this.GetComponent<PlayerStats>();
}
```

---

To answer your question, the `GetComponent` function impacting performance is greatly over exaggerated. You read this everywhere on the internet but it depends on how often it is used. If it is used once in a while or just in few  scripts then it's totally fine.

If you have hundreds instances of scripts using `GetComponent` in the `Update` function then that's when you will start noticing a little bit of performance hit because `GetComponent` is making call to the native side. *So, it depends on how often it is called and how many instances of scripts are making this call each frame.*

---

Comment: Yea you are right. I am using it like you wrote but up there i wrote from head and made mistake. Thank you anyway for more explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it really matters. I just did a check and using `for` loop that looped 1,000,000 times and found the exact same 0.02 time delay between both frames.

That being said, it would make your code cleaner because `Player.Stats.Asd` is cleaner than `Player.GetComponent<PlayerStats>().Asd`. It makes it more obvious what the intent is.  I'm sure it is still a micro optimization to store it as a variable with a `public PlayerStats Stats { get; set; }`, but that's really if you're using it all the time.

You shouldn't use a variable for every `Component` it has, because if you do that for every script, the memory being used will start to add up.

Also, note that I'm calling it `Stats` not `PlayerStats` because `Player.PlayerStats` is needlessly redundant. The actual *type* of it should be called `PlayerStats` yes, to not confuse it with, say, `EnemyStats`, but when you go to use both, having `Player.Stats` and `Enemy.Stats` is cleaner.

Comment: Did you set a max frames per second? I never considered time between frames until I read this and curious what FPS you were getting.

Comment: I was getting 60